# Conditionals simplification in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I have inherited code laden with ternary conditionals. This style is disallowed by our coding standards (which were introduced after the code has been written).

I am looking for a way to avoid rewriting all these statements manually. Is there a setting/plugin/sth. else in eclipse for this job?

Thank you.

PS. Though I am explicitly looking for a eclipse-based solution, I am not entirely averse to a nice ruby script for this ;)

EDIT : The "press Ctrl+1" approach by Joachim Sauer works for the example case, but does  not not for a typical eclipse-generated hashCode

```
int prime = 31;         
int result = 1;
result{Ctrl+1} = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
```

Pressing Ctrl+1 on the marked spot shows the following options only:
`Rename in file, rename in workspace, Extract local, Copy to criteria Editor, Extract to local variable`

If it would work universally, that would be great. Better still would be a solution that does not involve visting each occurrence.

I am using eclipse 3.7 on OpenSUSE 11, in case this is relevant.

Comment: If you want to do it properly, you have to parse the java source code (with java parser), otherwise, there will be always cases that your script is not catching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this sample code:

```
    boolean someCondition = true;
    int a = someCondition ? 1 : 2;
```

Place the cursor after the `a` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>. Then select "Replace conditional with 'if-else'".

That results in this code:

```
    int a;
    if (someCondition)
        a = 1;
    else
        a = 2;
```

Use Refactor > Inline (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>) as applicable to reduce unnecessary variable declarations.

Comment: @Joachim - Thanks, Joachim ,unfortunately the approach is not very reliable - works for your example case, but does  not not for a typical eclipse-generated hashCode. Please see my edit for illustration.